# Jetty migration from 6.x to 8.x and log4j per context logging

Tags: logging, log4j, migration, jetty

When I switch from 6.x to 8.x jetty all my applications do logging into the one log file (log file of one of my app) instead of separate ones as before.

My apps use DataNucleus, SpringSecurity, MyFaces, common-logging and my own  libs. I'm using Spring's log4jConfigLocation context parameter to set path to desired log4j.properties and 
org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener

It seems that issue caused by some class loading behavior change in new jetty.

I know there is the new way to set up context logging using MDC handler, postback and slf4j.

However I dislike that approach because it looks complicated to me and the logging configuration is shared across all contexts instead of having one log4j.properties per context.
Also I'm afraid it could have some overhead compared to old log4j direct way.

I have tried to put log4j-1.2.16.jar into each app's WEB-INF/lib to make it loading by web context class loader however log4j appender could not be created this way.

Are there any suggestions how to keep using log4j for per context logging in new jetty (8.x)?

Answer (score 1):

this should get you going with examples:

http://webtide.intalio.com/2011/08/sifting-logs-in-jetty-with-logback/

[edit] I should note the principles are the same re: logback and log4j in this instance

Comment: Thank you for your help. However I mentioned that I know about logback/mdc handler way. And described some reasons why I disliked it. Just let me ask additional question about suggested logback way. Say I have some jar with class pkg1.pkg2.TestClass and 2 app contexts where each one has own instance of this jar in WEB-INF/lib folder. jar classes use log4j/commons-logging for logging. Does logback allow me to use DEBUG level for the pkg1.pkg2.TestClass for the 1st app and ERROR level for the 2nd app with no overhead compared to the old way?